# Highcharts - how to position values closer to the Y axis

Tags: highcharts

Please see code. The values on the Y axis appear too far from the Y axis. I tried to get them closer but then the whole graph got distorted. I would appreciate any ideas on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance

```css
//Grafica 1
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('grafica1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['1350', '1400', '1450', '1500', '1550', '1699', '1750'],
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>',
            split: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                lineColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#ffffff'
                }
            }
        },
           series: [{
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
        }, {
            name: 'L. America',
            data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
        }, {
            name: 'S-E. Asia',
            data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
        }, {
            name: 'Japan',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'China',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Near East',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Asian CIS',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Russia',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'East Europe',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Central Europe',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'W. Europe - Nordic',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Nordic',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'N. America',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: added solution, check it

Comment: What do you mean by "too far", what did you try when you "tried to move them closer", and what, specifically, was the result that you are calling "the whole graph got distorted"? There are a number of things these could mean, and a number of possible solutions.  A fiddle is the best way to demonstrate both the problem, and your attempted solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help! the answer below solved the issue we were having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lables should be added in xAxis as

```
labels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return categories[this.value];
            }
        },
```

define categories as

```
var categories= ['1350', '1400', '1450', '1500', '1550', '1699', '1750'];
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vfa3o0o/)

finally js

```
$(function () {
var categories= ['1350', '1400', '1450', '1500', '1550', '1699', '1750'];
    Highcharts.chart('grafica1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
           labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return categories[this.value];
                }
            },
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>',
            split: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                lineColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#ffffff',
                }
            }
        },
           series: [{
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
        }, {
            name: 'L. America',
            data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
        }, {
            name: 'S-E. Asia',
            data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
        }, {
            name: 'Japan',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'China',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Near East',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Asian CIS',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Russia',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'East Europe',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Central Europe',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'W. Europe - Nordic',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Nordic',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'N. America',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }]
    });
});
```